# Parse multiple Json objects inside Json array only

Tags: android, json

Following the code,

```
"UserData":[  
      {  
         "userid":"8",
         "cmp_id":"2",
         "token":"VD8iIn0wMSRUVD9dZWxrd1Q\/JWZYeTU6Oz85ZntrMSxhM2x9YWsseVQwfTBkMHhxIlhkOjs\/OWY_",
         "first_name":"Rahul ",
         "last_name":"Sood",
         "username":"Soodcommunication",
         "level":"4",
         "amount":"0.000000000000000",
         "reward_amount":"7.192120767885948",
         "identity":"1",
         "adhar_uid":"287956228607",
         "pan_no":"BHFPS4357H",
         "valid_pan":"1",
         "verified_pan":"1",
         "email":"rahulsood22222@gmail.com",
         "mobile":"9736022222",
         "create_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
         "modify_date":"2016-08-05 16:47:21",
         "reff_id":"1",
         "collector":"0",
         "collector_id":"0",
         "tds":"0.000000000000000",
         "tax":"0.000000000000000",
         "mlm":"485.325000000000000",
         "profile_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/profile_8.png",
         "adhar_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/adhar_8.png",
         "pan_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/pan_8.png",
         "caping":"100",
         "last_login_time":"2016-08-05 16:47:21",
         "last_login_ip":"192.168.0.108",
         "last_activity":"2016-07-02 20:21:26",
         "auto_login":"1",
         "otomax_account":"1",
         "reseller_code":"0000",
         "allow_otomax_deduct":"1",
         "site_feature_request":"1",
         "allow_site_features":"1",
         "a_mtr_proofs":"0",
         "a_pre_paid":"1",
         "a_post_paid":"1",
         "a_dth":"1",
         "a_internet":"1",
         "a_mtr":"0",
         "a_ebill":"1",
         "a_insurance":"1",
         "a_datacard":"1",
         "gcm_id":null,
         "mac_address":"b4:34:54:12:fc:f1",
         "imei_number":"911383556485942",
         "is_otomax_owner":1
      },
      {  
         "userid":"27",
         "cmp_id":"2",
         "token":"VD8iIn0wMSRUVD9dZWxrd1Q\/JWZYeTU6Oz85ZntrMSxhM2x9YWsseVQwfTBkMHhxIlhkOjs\/OWY_",
         "first_name":"Rahul ",
         "last_name":"Sood",
         "username":"Soodcommunication",
         "level":"3",
         "amount":"0.000000000000000",
         "reward_amount":"0.033380000000000",
         "identity":"1",
         "adhar_uid":"287956228607",
         "pan_no":"BHFPS4357H",
         "valid_pan":"1",
         "verified_pan":"1",
         "email":"rahulsood22222@gmail.com",
         "mobile":"9736022222",
         "create_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
         "modify_date":"2016-08-05 16:47:21",
         "reff_id":"8",
         "collector":"0",
         "collector_id":"0",
         "tds":"0.000000000000000",
         "tax":"0.000000000000000",
         "mlm":"0.000000000000000",
         "profile_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/profile_8.png",
         "adhar_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/adhar_8.png",
         "pan_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/pan_8.png",
         "caping":"100",
         "last_login_time":"2016-08-05 16:47:21",
         "last_login_ip":"192.168.0.108",
         "last_activity":"2016-01-04 14:38:31",
         "auto_login":"1",
         "otomax_account":"1",
         "reseller_code":"0000",
         "allow_otomax_deduct":"1",
         "site_feature_request":"1",
         "allow_site_features":"1",
         "a_mtr_proofs":"0",
         "a_pre_paid":"1",
         "a_post_paid":"1",
         "a_dth":"1",
         "a_internet":"1",
         "a_mtr":"0",
         "a_ebill":"1",
         "a_insurance":"1",
         "a_datacard":"1",
         "gcm_id":null,
         "mac_address":"b4:34:54:12:fc:f1",
         "imei_number":"911383556485942",
         "is_otomax_owner":1
      },
      {  
         "userid":"28",
         "cmp_id":"2",
         "token":"VD8iIn0wMSRUVD9dZWxrd1Q\/JWZYeTU6Oz85ZntrMSxhM2x9YWsseVQwfTBkMHhxIlhkOjs\/OWY_",
         "first_name":"Rahul ",
         "last_name":"Sood",
         "username":"Soodcommunication",
         "level":"2",
         "amount":"0.000000000000000",
         "reward_amount":"0.422603879502350",
         "identity":"1",
         "adhar_uid":"287956228607",
         "pan_no":"BHFPS4357H",
         "valid_pan":"1",
         "verified_pan":"1",
         "email":"rahulsood22222@gmail.com",
         "mobile":"9736022222",
         "create_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
         "modify_date":"2016-08-05 16:47:21",
         "reff_id":"27",
         "collector":"0",
         "collector_id":"0",
         "tds":"0.000000000000000",
         "tax":"0.000000000000000",
         "mlm":"0.000000000000000",
         "profile_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/profile_8.png",
         "adhar_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/adhar_8.png",
         "pan_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/pan_8.png",
         "caping":"100",
         "last_login_time":"2016-08-05 16:47:21",
         "last_login_ip":"192.168.0.108",
         "last_activity":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
         "auto_login":"1",
         "otomax_account":"1",
         "reseller_code":"0000",
         "allow_otomax_deduct":"1",
         "site_feature_request":"1",
         "allow_site_features":"1",
         "a_mtr_proofs":"0",
         "a_pre_paid":"1",
         "a_post_paid":"1",
         "a_dth":"1",
         "a_internet":"1",
         "a_mtr":"0",
         "a_ebill":"1",
         "a_insurance":"1",
         "a_datacard":"1",
         "gcm_id":null,
         "mac_address":"b4:34:54:12:fc:f1",
         "imei_number":"911383556485942",
         "is_otomax_owner":1
      },
      {  
         "userid":"29",
         "cmp_id":"2",
         "token":"VD8iIn0wMSRUVD9dZWxrd1Q\/JWZYeTU6Oz85ZntrMSxhM2x9YWsseVQwfTBkMHhxIlhkOjs\/OWY_",
         "first_name":"Rahul ",
         "last_name":"Sood",
         "username":"Soodcommunication",
         "level":"1",
         "amount":"50000.000000000000000",
         "reward_amount":"0.211391062965119",
         "identity":"1",
         "adhar_uid":"287956228607",
         "pan_no":"BHFPS4357H",
         "valid_pan":"1",
         "verified_pan":"1",
         "email":"rahulsood22222@gmail.com",
         "mobile":"9736022222",
         "create_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
         "modify_date":"2016-08-05 16:47:21",
         "reff_id":"28",
         "collector":"0",
         "collector_id":"0",
         "tds":"0.000000000000000",
         "tax":"4.335500000000000",
         "mlm":"0.000000000000000",
         "profile_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/profile_8.png",
         "adhar_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/adhar_8.png",
         "pan_name":"PROOFS_DATA\/USER_PROOFS\/user_8\/pan_8.png",
         "caping":"100",
         "last_login_time":"2016-08-05 16:47:21",
         "last_login_ip":"192.168.0.108",
         "last_activity":"2016-07-01 16:09:03",
         "auto_login":"1",
         "otomax_account":"1",
         "reseller_code":"0000",
         "allow_otomax_deduct":"1",
         "site_feature_request":"1",
         "allow_site_features":"1",
         "a_mtr_proofs":"0",
         "a_pre_paid":"1",
         "a_post_paid":"1",
         "a_dth":"1",
         "a_internet":"1",
         "a_mtr":"0",
         "a_ebill":"1",
         "a_insurance":"1",
         "a_datacard":"1",
         "gcm_id":null,
         "mac_address":"b4:34:54:12:fc:f1",
         "imei_number":"911383556485942",
         "is_otomax_owner":1
      }
   ]
```

Comment: You might be interested in Gson or Jackson json libraries.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{"+jsonStr+"}");  

JSONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("UserData");

   for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
   {
       JSONObject object = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

       // do some stuff like this....

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),object.getInt("userid"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),object.getString("token"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

    }
```